# Ignore parent CSS in oder to change background of child

Tags: html, css

I have created Two tables Parent and its child and i want to use different CSS for both but the problem is child table is also loading css of parent table all i want that my child table should have white background, I tried `inline styling` for child table, `#ID` , `.Class` wise styling for child table but i am not able to set the background to white where as i am able to change its fontsize with my css, Kindly let me know is there a way to make the child table use its own derived css?

In the following image ABC is parent table and inside the popover there is a heading of `Top events` which is child table:

[image: Image help]

Comment: Can you post your HTML code and CSS classes? Have you tried using the `!important` attribute for the child class?

Comment: please post your current CSS

Comment: please add your current html and css, possibly in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @jamis0n thanks kindly post it as answer so i can accept, using !important; did the trick

Comment: Awesome! Just posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `!important` attribute for the child class? This will override any previous styles assigned for this attribute and allow you to find out if the style is a problem or the order of the classes.

Note: As a best practice, avoid adding `!important` everywhere and only use when absolutely necessary. In this case, you could put the child class after the parent class in the css declarations. Using `!important` can help you figure out if your classes are stylisticly correct but in the wrong order. Then, try ordering your child's CSS class after the parents so that the imporant is not needed anymore.  [Read more here...](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/)

I think that @Jacqui's answer below should also solve the issue.

Comment: This is a very bad solution. Use specificity to solve the problem and never the `!important` declaration. Should not be upvoted at all.

Comment: @Christoph Why the downvote? While it solved his problem, I mentioned that its not a good practice to use this and that the style sheet classes should cascade in a way that accomplishes the same without `!important`

Comment: Why do you recommend it if you even know it's wrong? There are several other ways to accomplish the same result. You are encouraging a novice to use wrong style.

Comment: While thats a good point, I would say that using `!important` helped him understand that the actual styles were correct, but they were in the wrong order. So as a follow up for the OP, try ordering your child's CSS class after the parents so that the imporant is not needed.

Comment: Fair enough! I like the way you think :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

CSS

```
.parent-table {
  /* styling for the parent table */
}
.parent-table .child-table {
  /* styling for the child table */
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="parent-table">
  <tr><td><table class="child-table">...</table>...</td></tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: This is a nice and recommended way to override parent's styles. +1